# Error when starting Glassfish Server. Password Required at localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

Has anyone ever seen this kind of error? This is shown when i'm trying to deploy the Glassfish Server App

You can see Screenshots here:

[image: Glassfish Error Password Required]

[image: Glassfish Error Wrong user name or password]

It is in Italian Language and I don't know how to change it in English (if anyone know please tell me how and I rewrite it for you).

I have not set any password for the Glassfish Admin Console I'm sure. The error is displayed in the last line and translated into English is:

> Information: User [root] host 127.0.0.1 does not have access for administration or you have typed user name and password incorrect

Comment: *"It is in Italian Language and I don't know how to change it in English"*: change the platform or environment default locale. On screens I see that you're using Eclipse. It uses the operating system platform default locale as default locale. You can override it by `-nl` argument on the Eclipse executabele: `eclipse -nl en`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installing for the fist time glassfish creates a default domain "domain1". The user is admin and the password is adminadmin. You should double check that eclipse is using this "domain1".

If you can't make it work a simple solution would be create a new domain in glassfish assigning a new user and password and configure eclipse to use this new domain.

Before trying anything in eclipse the first troubleshoot would be entering the admin console from a browser. If Im not wrong the default port of domain1 is 4848.

Comment: I've just inserted user:admin password: blank. Now glassfish server starts, but the Java Console writes this again:

Information: User [root] host 127.0.0.1 does not have access for administration or you have typed user name and password incorrect

Comment: yes i did, but it re-ask me user and password again because i've setted user: admin and nothing for password during installation of Glassfish 3.1. The real problem now is the last phrase that i've wrote.

Comment: Seeing as you're just starting. I'd clober the domain and start over, this time using the default password or picking one.

Comment: If I use Anonymous Connection for Admin Command (in the Overview of Glassfish Server) The problem is not shown. Why that??

Comment: "Information: User [root] host 127.0.0.1 does not have access for administration or you have typed user name and password incorrect" this looks like an OS user permission problem. This user host is the user that you are providing for your domain or is the OS user that you are using to start your domain? If this is the domain user I must remark again that the default user is "admin"

Comment: "The user is admin and the password is adminadmin." Not any more with GlassFish 4.

Answer (score 10):

In glassfish 4, **empty** password worked for me.

Comment: Update: Eclipse Plugin did not work with Glassfish 4.1.1 for me. Indeed it worked well with Glassfish 4.1 and login: admin, password: EMPTY

Answer (score 4):

If an admin passowrd was mentioned at the time of domain-creation; the same password has to be mentioned during configuring glassfish server in eclipse.

ALSO, make sure that the option '**Use Anonymous Connection for Admin Commands**' is '**UNCHECKED**'. By default, it will be in checked mode.

[image: GlassFish Eclipse Configuration]

You could see this option by *double clicking* on the '*GlassFish xxxxx server*' entry in 'Servers' palette, in eclipse.

Thanks,
Raj, Linu.

Comment: Unchecking that anonymous option works for me in Eclipse, but I still get the error from Netbeans. In Netbeans, I cannot find this option anywhere to uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding XDB error, i was able to login to admin console, uncheck the security under system-config->http services->http-listeners->xxxxxx.   Once i unchecked the security and try to log back in, it did not prompted the login and gave me screen showing server status